# Orientdb connection issue while connecting remote server

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I am using tikerpop orient API, its working fine on local but when I try to connect remote IP, it get failed.

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:12.34.567.89:2480/demodb", "admin", "admin");
OrientGraph txGraph = factory.getTx();
```

I am able to access demodb on server using orient studio but can not connect from local spring boot application code.
While bean creating getting following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getGraphDB' defined in class path resource [com/straviso/interaction/config/OrientDBConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph]: Factory method 'getGraphDB' threw exception; nested exception is com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'demodb'
    DB name="demodb"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.straviso.interaction.SpringOrientDBApplication.main(SpringOrientDBApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph]: Factory method 'getGraphDB' threw exception; nested exception is com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'demodb'
    DB name="demodb"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'demodb'
    DB name="demodb"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBRemote.open(OrientDBRemote.java:89) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:898) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:440) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:303) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:261) ~[orientdb-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:147) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:78) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:137) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory$1.getGraph(OrientGraphFactory.java:87) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.getTx(OrientGraphFactory.java:224) ~[orientdb-graphdb-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.straviso.interaction.config.OrientDBConfiguration.getGraphDB(OrientDBConfiguration.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.straviso.interaction.config.OrientDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$685f621b.CGLIB$getGraphDB$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.straviso.interaction.config.OrientDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$685f621b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f9e7274.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.straviso.interaction.config.OrientDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$685f621b.getGraphDB(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [12.34.567.89:2480]
    DB name="demodb"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1559) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1413) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:398) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentRemote.internalOpen(ODatabaseDocumentRemote.java:205) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBRemote.open(OrientDBRemote.java:86) ~[orientdb-client-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

What correct way to connect remote server?

Comment: 2480 is the http port, switch to  2430. Moreover, 2430 is the default value, just remove is:

Comment: when port is removed=Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [12.34.567.89:2424]
DB name="demodb"

when port is 2430 = Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [12.34.567.89:2430]
 DB name="demodb"

From browser I am able to login on 12.34.567.89:2430

Comment: Orient by default Listens binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 . Opened the port and was able to connect.

Comment: Sorry, binary port is 2424.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to the Tinkerpop API for gremlin traversals this is exposed on port 8182.

So if you are, for example, running the server in docker you'll need to expose port 8182 first before you can establish a remote connection to it.